# Why We can input more character than specified in Data Type SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using Elmasri Company Database.

While creating this table

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
( Fname           VARCHAR(10)   NOT NULL,
  Minit           CHAR,
  Lname           VARCHAR(20)      NOT NULL,
  Ssn             CHAR(9)          NOT NULL,
  Bdate           DATE,
  Address         VARCHAR(30),
  Sex             CHAR(1),
  Salary          DECIMAL(5),
  Super_ssn       CHAR(9),
  Dno             INT               NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY   (Ssn));
```

I try to input more character than specified there, in the SEX with CHAR(1).

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE
VALUES      ('John','B','Smith',123456789,'1965-01-09','731 Fondren, Houston TX','M',30000,333445555,5),
            ('Franklin','T','Wong',333445555,'1965-12-08','638 Voss, Houston TX','M',40000,888665555,5),
            ('Alicia','J','Zelaya',999887777,'1968-01-19','3321 Castle, Spring TX','F',25000,987654321,4),
            ('Jennifer','S','Wallace',987654321,'1941-06-20','291 Berry, Bellaire TX','F',43000,888665555,4),
            ('Ramesh','K','Narayan',666884444,'1962-09-15','975 Fire Oak, Humble TX','M',38000,333445555,5),
            ('Joyce','A','English',453453453,'1972-07-31','5631 Rice, Houston TX','FEMALE',25000,333445555,5),
            ('Ahmad','V','Jabbar',987987987,'1969-03-29','980 Dallas, Houston TX','MALE',25000,987654321,4),
            ('James','E','Borg',888665555,'1937-11-10','450 Stone, Houston TX','ANYTHING',55000,null,1);
```

I give input with **MALE**, **FEMALE** and **ANYTHING**.

I use DB Browser for SQLite, and I can save it to my `file.db`.

So, what is the purpose We specify that Sex with CHAR(1), if We can do something like that?

[Screen Shoot of SQL Execution in DB Browser for SQLite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSicY.png)

Edit : *answering Question from tgdavies*

[Screen Shoot of Browse Data menu from DB Browser for SQLite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdVGR.png)

Comment: Your execution screenshot is just logging the query. Have you checked what data is in the table?

Comment: Yes, I have. The data inputted, can be saved too.

Comment: See https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q9